# How do I play YouTube content in the background?

Tags: youtube-api, google-play, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I am making an app to play YouTube videos in a popup window, but I see no way to play it in the background. When I try to update the app in the store, Google rejects it. After asking the Google Play team, they said:

> Thank you for contacting the Google Play Team.
>
> During review, we found that your app violates both YouTube API Terms of Service and section 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement (DDA). Your app enables the user to play YouTube content in the background (opens a separate window) while the app is not active (meaning all playback should stop, once the user closes the app). This rejection does not impact the standing of your Google Play Developer Account. However, repeated violations may result in the suspension of this app or your Google Play Developer account.
>
> Before submitting your app again, make sure you’ve corrected all policy violations.

How can I fix this problem? Do I have to remove the popup window completely or just close the service when the app is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well considering youtube now charges money to do what your doing, theres no way they would allow you to do that, yes you will probably need to disable playback when the app is hidden, but that defeats your purpose.

Comment: but theres some app in store do same ?

Comment: @user2423314: it's possible they just haven't been caught. If it's against YouTube's policy to play videos in the background, there really isn't a way around this.